# Out of Memory Error

Tags: memory

I am currently constructing matrices, but I'm having problems with memory. When I evaluate some cells, the kernel quits due to lack of memory. I tried `ClearSystemCache`, `Clear["Global'*"]`, and used `MemoryInUse[]` to check how much memory was freed, but not it was not enough.

When I use both clear functions and do a `MemoryInUse[]` from the top of my notebook, I get 38 441 336, which doesn't seem right considering I haven't started any computation. I would like to be able to clear as much memory as possible to continue with other calculations. Thank you.

Edit:
I am working with 100x100x100x100 matrices since my goal is to do a `ListVectorPlot` with them. I tried `SetPrecision[x, 1]` for each element in the matrix, but it still doesn't work. I also tried with smaller matrices, like 25x25x25x25, still nothing. `$HistoryLength=0` as well as `Quit[]` frees some memory but not enough.

Here is my code for producing this large matrix which I get data from a file:

```
(*vector plot of expectation values for positive psi *)  
expectvect = Import["Greens_Expectation.m", "Table"];  
momentum = Import["Greens_Momentum.m", "Table"];  
vectorplot = {};  
i = 1;  
m = 1;  
n = 1;  
kx = -Pi;  
ky = -Pi;  
For[m = 1, i <= l^2*3, i += 3,  
 tempvect = {{SetPrecision[
     Evaluate[Sequence @@ ToExpression[momentum[[i]]]], 1], 
    SetPrecision[
     Evaluate[Sequence @@ ToExpression[momentum[[i + 1]]]], 
     1]}, {SetPrecision[
     Evaluate[ Sequence @@ ToExpression[expectvect[[i]]]], 1], 
    SetPrecision[
     Evaluate[ Sequence @@ ToExpression[expectvect[[i + 1]]]], 1]}};  
 vectorplot = Join[ vectorplot, {tempvect}];  
 (*Print[vectorplot]*)  
 ]  
ListVectorPlot[vectorplot]
```

Comment: What was the input that caused the kernel to quit? It is normal for a small amount of memory, such as 38 MB, to be used after startup.

Comment: Try $HistoryLength=0.

Comment: Very difficult to answer without code to reproduce. Apart from heeding  @SjoerdC.deVries´ advice and starting with a new kernel, there is not a lot to be done without more information.

Comment: If you use multi-dimensional matrices memory use can go up quickly: a 1000x1000x1000 matrix with machine precision reals takes up 8GB. So, what kind of matrices are you working with?

Comment: In this case, MaxMemoryUsed and MemoryConstraint may be your friend in tracking down the location of the issue. You may have an intermediate symbolic result that is blowing out your memory footprint.

Comment: Please take a look at the formatting help and optimize the browsing experience for others: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: What do you get running ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[]`` on either `expectvect` or `momentum`? If it returns false, then a 100x100x100x100 matrix that is unpacked can easily take up a lot of space.

Comment: `Developer`PackedArrayQ[]` returns false on both. How exactly would you construct a packed array? I constructed my array and put a `ToPackedArray[vectorplot]` after, but it still crashes. I also tried `ToPackedArray[vectorplot]` inside the loop with the same results.

Comment: @Alex how big are the m-files you are importing? Also what data do they contain - reals, integers, complex, a mixture of those?

Comment: @blochwave the m-files are about 25 kb each, having a mixture of reals and complex